# How to access Anaconda in PowerShell after reinstallation?

Tags: windows, powershell, anaconda, installation

Anaconda was installed by Systems Team on my work computer.
For reasons beyond this topic, they installed in Program Files, which I think is non-optimal.
So I ask permission to remove the installation and reinstall it via standard procedures.

When I open Anaconda PowerShell prompt it is still pointing to the Program Files installation which I have removed.
I have also checked the Path environmental variable, and there is nothing looking like Anaconda is still there.

How can I get Anaconda PowerShell prompt to work again?

It should be noted that `conda` command does work in regular command prompt.

Thanks.

Comment: Program Files *is* "standard procedure."  This is off-topic for this site and should be directed to Super User.  The problem is with your `PATH` environment variable.

Comment: @MaximilianBurszley Program Files is *not* the standard procedure for Anaconda installations. The default is to install it into the User directory (AppData somewhere). As given by Peter below, there is a well-defined procedure and answer to this question, which has nothing to do with `PATH`, which is also not the recommended approach. Also, this question relates to software commonly used for programming. As such, I believe it is on topic here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Initialize conda for use with Powershell via

```
conda init powershell
```

This command should be run in Anaconda Prompt.

Answer (score 0):

Before following @Peter's solution, I was able to track the problem via a more rustic procedure.

1. Right click on Start Menu's Anaconda PowerShell Prompt, and select `Open File Location`.
2. Right click on the icon's Properties, select Shortcut tab > Target field.
3. Copy the command to a text editor, and noticed it was still using an old location.
4. Changing the command to point to the right location did fix the problem.

... but that is only the command from the Start Menu, the rest is done by what was suggested before.

Thanks for the help.